# Bitcoin trading at bitstamp

Tags: trading, bitstamp

I would like to start trading with Bitcoins. My only question for now is:

Can you lose more money, that you deposited on Bitstamp? If yes, how?

> Step by step question:
>
> 1. I deposit 1 bitcoin *(balance **1** bitcoin)*
> 2. I trade with bitcoins *(balance **0** bitcoins)*
> 3. I lose *(balance **-1** bitcoin)* <-- Can i get in **negative state**, or is there a **limit of 0**?

Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitstamp does not offer credit, so your balance can not go below zero.